# refreshing data in a portion of the html code

Tags: css

I saw this piece of code at the https://analytics.usa.gov/ website. I am really curious about how it works. In particlar, how do they refresh just that part of the page?

```
<section id="realtime" data-block="realtime" data-source="https://analytics.usa.gov/data/live/realtime.json" data-refresh="15" class="loaded">
          <h2 id="current_visitors" class="data">56,796</h2>
          <div class="chart_subtitle">people on government websites now</div>
</section>
```

Any pointers to documentation/tutorials would be helpful.

Comment: downvoter cares to comment? Maybe I can improve the question, or simply delete it if the information is really available? That would be helpful.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz: I have. Does that imply I have to magically know that that's the solution?

Comment: No, I was just asking if you knew about it. Usually that is the answer to partially updating a view.

Answer (score 1):

how about reading what they said to it:

https://18f.gsa.gov/2015/03/19/how-we-built-analytics-usa-gov/

there they explain how they did it

Answer (score 0):

If you view the source, you'll see this message:

```
<!--

Hi! Welcome to our source code.

This dashboard uses data from the Digital Analytics Program, a US
government team inside the General Services Administration, an independent federal agency. It's built and hosted largely by 18F, another GSA team.


For a detailed tech breakdown of how 18F built this site:

https://18f.gsa.gov/2015/03/19/how-we-built-analytics-usa-gov/


This is a fully open source project, and your contributions are welcome.

Frontend static site: https://github.com/GSA/analytics.usa.gov
Backend data reporting: https://github.com/18F/analytics-reporter

-->
```

Check the git repositories if you're interested in the technologies used.